# Intercept when a user is about to leave a navigation page

Tags: javascript, events, modal-dialog, onbeforeunload

I would like to intercept when a user is about to leave the product page of my site, to make a personalized message appear in a modal.

I tried the 'beforeunload' event handler but it appears, in FireFox, a confirmation message about the desire to leave the page, default by the browser and being able to customize only the text;
In Edge, does not show a confirmation message to leave the page but allows the user to continue browsing elsewhere regardless of the preventDefault().

Is there another event handler or a way to make this modal appear without getting the warning from the browser?

thanks!

```
   window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      let page_name = prestashop.page.page_name;

      if (page_name == 'index') {
        const modalProductPage = `
  <div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 class="display-4">Hello, world!</h1>
  <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
  <hr class="my-4">
  <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
  <p class="lead">
  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Buy</a>
  </p>
  </div>
  `
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log('event attived!')
          $('.modal-body').html(modalProductPage)
          $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show')
        }, 500);

      }
    })
```

Comment: onbeforeunload is really the only way of doing this, and its by design. Would be pretty annoying if you could have complete control over user navigation like that.

Comment: I agree with you, I think it's invasive, but it's a request I've received;

 I've also tried with an event handler to keep track of the URL and its change, but it only works if the user tries to manually navigate through the URL. 

Before proposing (the best solution, in my opinion) the handling of a modal with setTimeOut(), I wanted to make sure that there was no way around it.

 Thanks for the feedback!